# Проблема с разделами флешки

Tags: linux, partition, manjaro, gparted

Задача: заставить работать флешку как загрузочный носитель( дистрбутив Manjaro ) и хранилище файлов одновременно.
Возникла проблема с добавлением раздела на флешку с дистром манджары, записанным с помощью SUSE Image Writer. GParted ругается на рекурсивный раздел. В гугле ничего кроме "Используй Unetbootin"
 я не нашел.
 Отформатировал флешку, вручную создал раздел с размером в точности до байта как у образа дистра и записал средствоми GParted, после сделал раздел скрытым и загрузочным. Второй раздел создался нормально, но теперь перестал компьютер загружатся с флешки, как с загрузочного носителя.
Чем я пробывал записать еще:
dd: сбивает все разделы, приводя в некорректное состояние флешку
unetbootin: некорректно загружает manjaro, вызывая kernel panic или не загружается вообще
SUSE Image Writer: рекурсивный раздел
Текущее состояние флешки:

```html
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Диск /dev/sdb: 14,7 GiB, 15795748864 байт, 30851072 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0xea3f6006

Устр-во    Загрузочный  начало    Конец  Секторы Размер Идентификатор Тип
/dev/sdb1  *              2048  3581887  3579840   1,7G            17 Скрытый HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2              3581952 30851071 27269120    13G             c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Что делать теперь? Что я упустил?

Comment: *В гугле ничего кроме "Используй Unetbootin" я не нашел* — искать надо было по ключевым словам «install grub to flash drive». например, первый результат: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Изначально задача "поставить grub" не стояла. По идее, не  используя мультизагрузку и не устанавливая другие установщики GRUB не нужен, веть без него ранее запускался установщик

Comment: «ведь ранее запускался» — вам-то это не подходит. вам надо не «как ранее», а «по-новому». если вы хотите именно сохранить iso-образ как таковой, то вам надо организовать загрузку с этого образа. осуществить это может какой-нибудь «навороченный» загрузчик. чаще всего для таких целей используют именно grub, хотя можно обойтись и более ограниченным syslinux. возможно, и какой-нибудь другой справится, но тут я ничего не подскажу. а вопрос ваш очень «широкий» и требует написания целой статьи, а не краткого ответа.

Comment: а *kernel panic* у вас возникает из-за того, что вы не передаёте [необходимые именно манджаровским стартовым скриптам](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/booting-manjaro-iso-using-grub2/3132) параметры (довольно эксклюзивные — в других дистрибутивах я таких не встречал), по которым они смогут обнаружить iso-файл.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Файлы из iso уже лежат на разделе /dev/sdb1 (и раздел помечен загрузочным).Если syslinux, который используется в unetbootin не справился с загрузкой манджары, то что сделает груб? Хотелось увидеть дефлотное окно манджары(с выбором языка и прочими вкусностями), а не иной загрузчик. В данный момент при загрузке с флешки я вижу черный экран с мигающим курсором в начале.

Comment: нет, по поводу syslinux, я, пожалуй, поторопился: для вашей ситуации его дириктива `memdisk` вряд ли подойдёт — загрузка в память всего iso (учитывая, что большая часть этой информации ещё раз повторно будет загружена в память) — это довольно накладно.

Comment: *Файлы из iso уже лежат на разделе* — ну, значит, осталось лишь передать правильные параметры программе linux (далее их прочитают стартовые скрипты). ссылку я привёл выше.